# Embedding PDF with fullscreen option

Tags: php, html, pdf, iframe, embedding

Is there any way to add the fullscreen option to the PDF that is embedded using iframe ?

```
<iframe src="http://www.web.com/test.pdf"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe DC View SDK kept throwing errors constantly for some reason. So I tried [Mozilla’s PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) and seems to be working just fine, even on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably control the PDF experience unless you replace the default viewer of the browser. They all behave slightly differently. However, the new free Adobe DC View SDK is a client-side JavaScript PDF viewer that will allow you to embed a PDF in your HTML page and it has a full-screen option. By using this viewer, the PDF will behave consistently and have a consistent UI across all browsers.

[image]

The code would look like this...

```
<div id="adobe-dc-view" style="height: 360px; width: 500px;"></div>
<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){ 
    var adobeDCView = 
        new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
    adobeDCView.previewFile({
      content:{location: {url: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf"}},
      metaData:{fileName: "Bodea Brochure.pdf"}
    }, {embedMode: "SIZED_CONTAINER"});
  });
</script>
```

You can get the clientID here.
https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html

Comment: Main.js throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at main.js?ver=5.4.2:1 at Object.Be7j (main.js?ver=5.4.2:1)` for some reason.

Comment: Did you sign up for a clientID and use it? Can you send me a link to your page?